# Using --no-tablespace option when backing up Magento 2 databases

Tags: magento2, database

I run a nightly cron job to back-up to backup my SQL databases using mysqldump.

This has started to display the following error on all my databases:

```
Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

One of the solutions for this is to run the mysqldump using the --no-tablespace option.

Is this a safe practice, and recommended practice, to implement with Magento 2 databases?

Comment: I've done several migrations and database backups and ran into this issue a few times. Never had an issue when using the --no-tablespace option

Comment: I've tried testing this after backing up with the --no-tablespace option, deleting and restoring the DB and it seems fine.